# How to access values of 2d array (returned by php file in jquery autocomplete) in JavaScript Function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I think it is pretty simple but I am unable to solve it.

This is JQuery:

```
$( "#tut_search" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: "PHP_Code/MyAjax.php?page=tut_search_ac"
});
```

This is php script which is returning 2d array to JQuery autocomplete:

```
$keyward = $_REQUEST['term'];
$query = "SELECT title FROM tutorial WHERE title LIKE '%$keyward%' ORDER BY title";
$rs = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()." in query $query");
if($rs)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        $contents[] = array( "label" => $row['id'], "value" => $row['title'], "detail" => $row['text'] );
    }
}   
echo json_encode($contents);
```

This is my own created JavaScript function. I want to call it on onclick of each autocomplete list item:

```
//This function should be called when autocomplete list item is clicked or selected
function loader(label, value)
{
    //Here I want to perform processing on `label` which is actually an id & returned by php script

    //Here I want to perform processing on `value` which is also returned by php script
}
```

**These are my two requirements:**

1. I want to call function `loader(label, value)` when any
   item of autocomplete list is clicked or selected.
2. I also want to access the values of `label` and `value` in `loader(laber, value)` function. 
   (`label` and `value` are two separate values
   which I returned in php script).

Please give me some solution to do above two tasks.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  If `loader` is supposed to do preprocessing, perhaps you meant to instead use a function for the `source` option? Using a string value for `source` already does basic processing for you; after selection, the selected *label* is discarded and the *value* is placed in the autocomplete (you can retrieve it with `.val()` as you would any input value)

Comment: I want to bind my own-created-function to list items. Function should also access and process all the data remotely returned by php script. @blgt please reread my question, I have also edited/reformed it.

Comment: 1st task of binding function has been solved by using JQuery's `select` property. like this `select:function(event,ui){ loader(); }`. Now I just want to access `label` and `value` in my `loader()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the select property of the jQueryUI [Autocomplete](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) to call your function.

```
// on autocomplete initialization
$( "#tut_search" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: "PHP_Code/MyAjax.php?page=tut_search_ac",
    select: function(event,ui){}
});

// or after initialization
$( "#tut_search" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

You can access the label and value properties from `ui.item.label`  and `ui.item.value`  That being said i would call your function inside the function(event,ui){//here} and pass in the parameters from there

Comment: Nice its working. But it is 50% solution. I also want to access `label` and `value` in the function. Have you any solution about remaining part?

Comment: everything working perfect just one problem remaining. I was passed ID to `label` index (from php script) but it's also showing `value`'s value. Additionally I passed more indexes (`detail` in my question) for additional information. But except `label` and `value` all remaining indexes are showing NULL value. Have you any solution?

Comment: For that i would recommend posting another question.  That gets into an entire different answer.  Maybe start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683051/jquery-autocomplete-get-id-as-selected-label)